# How can $B=\{[a,+\infty)| a \in \mathbb R \}$ be the base of a topology over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

> Given $B=\{[a,+\infty)| a \in \mathbb R  \}$
>
> Is B base of a topology over $\mathbb R$?

The answer in my handout  is yes, no explanation, but how can that be, if it does not satisfies the first condition for being a base: the union of all elements of the base must be the whole set $\mathbb R$. 
If it were $B=\{(a,+\infty)| a \in \mathbb R  \}$ I wouldn't argue.

What is wrong here?

Comment: for any $x\in\mathbb R$, take $a\le x$; then $x\in[a,\infty)$ so $x$ is in the union of all elements of $B$

Comment: and what about the fact that the elements of B are not open sets?In fact they would be closed sets, because the complement is open

Comment: the elements of $B$ are not open sets in *the usual* topology for $\mathbb R$, but that doesn't mean they're not a base of *a* topology for $\mathbb R$

Comment: By definition, the elements in the base of the topology are open sets. A topology on a set defines what the open sets are. But furthermore, even if a set is closed, that does not mean it isn't open; for example, in any topological space, the empty set and the whole set are open and closed (clopen).

Comment: For any set $X$, any collection $B$ of subsets of $X$ is a base for a topology on $X$ iff (i) $\,\cup B=X$ (i.e. each $x\in X$ belongs to at least one $b\in B$), and (ii)  whenever $b_1,b_2 \in B$ and $x\in b_1\cap b_2$ there exists $b_3\in B$ with $x\in b_3\subseteq b_1\cap b_2$.... Note that if $b_1\cap b_2\in B$ whenever $b_1,b_2 \in B$ then (ii) is automatic (with $b_3=b_1\cap b_2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing; if $x \in \Bbb R$, $x \in [x, +\infty) \in B$, so the first axiom is satisfied. The elements of $B$ are by definition open sets for the topology they generate. (They're not open in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ in this case, but that doesn't matter -- we're defining a *new* topology here.)

Answer (score 1):

Take $x\in\mathbb R$. Then $x\in[x,\infty)\subset\bigcup_{a\in\mathbb R}[a,\infty)$. So, yes, $\bigcup_{a\in\mathbb R}[a,\infty)=\mathbb R$.